# Entity Framework and enum with flags not mapped to db

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have class with enum:

```
 [Flags]
    public enum FlyerStatus
    {
        None = 0,
        Deleted = 1 << 0,
        Validated = 1 << 1,
        Active = 1 << 2
    }
```

There is not configuration in Fluent.API or Data Annotations.

When I add migrations or automigrations are enabled the property is not mapped to db. That column do no exist. No error or smth. What is going on?

```
public FlyerStatus Status;
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with enum and not because your `Status` is a *field* and not *property* (did you forget `get/set`)?

Comment: What @IvanStoev said, also, what *version* of Entity Framework are you using? EF5 had some issues with enumerations (if I recall correctly) and they didn't map properly. (I believe you had to create an `int` column that mapped to the DB, then parse it in the enumeration property.)

Answer (score 0):

With newest versions, if you annotate the property like this, it will get mapped to an int column in Entity Framework / database:

```
[EnumDataType(typeof(FlyerStatus))]
public FlyerStatus Status { get; set; }
```